# How to tell Visual Studio 2015 to use the latest UCRT from Windows 10 SDK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 3 (which bundles UCRT 10.0.10240.0) to build a DLL with UCRT statically linked (`/MT`).

That version of UCRT contains a bug (deadlock in setlocale), I have therefore installed Windows 10 SDK with UCRT 10.0.10586.0, but Visual Studio keeps using it's own version, 10.0.10240.0.

Hence my question - how do I get Visual Studio to link with the latest UCRT libs?

Comment: Changing the project's Target Platform Version setting to 10.0.10586.0 is the simple way.  Changing the VC++ Directories settings for Include and Library is the hard way.

Comment: Where is that specified, exactly? I have only "Visual Studio 2015" and "Visual Studio 2015 (xp)" options in "target platform"

Comment: "Target Platform Version", not "Platform Toolset".  General page, second item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans Passant mentioned in his comment, after installing **Windows 10 SDK**, it is possible to target the new UCRT in **Visual Studio 2015** using the "*Target Platform Version*" drop-down in Project Settings.

[image]

If this is not done (Target Platform Version is 8.1), Visual Studio will continue to use UCRT 10.0.10240.0.

However, "*VS2015 Command Prompt*" seems to automatically pick up the latest UCRT.