# How many Windows SDKs can I have installed?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2015

In trying to debug a VS2015 MFC native C++ build problem I realized my knowledge is weak about SDKs. I just installed Update 2 for VS2015 and now the $(WindowsSDK_IncludePath) variable is set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt. (I didn't check this before the update.)

But I notice that in this location:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits
I have the following folders:
8.0, 8.1, 10, NETFXSDK

Does that mean I currently have several SDKs installed right now?

I also found these folders at this location:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
v10.0A, v6.0A, v7.0A, v7.1A, v8.0, v8.0A, v8.1, v8.1A

And if I have several SDKs installed, is it possible to target different ones for different VS2015 projects?

This link was helpful but in my project the Target Platform and Target Platform Version fields are totally blank:
[How to tell Visual Studio 2015 to use the latest UCRT from Windows 10 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414890/how-to-tell-visual-studio-2015-to-use-the-latest-ucrt-from-windows-10-sdk)

I have not seen a good overview in the documentation and I just need a better understanding here and I appreciate any tips.

mitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple SDKs installed. The property pages in Visual Studio allow you to choose one. The Target Platform Version is not what you want. In the page you referenced, look further down in the property list for Platform Toolset.

The details are given in this MSDN article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

Here's the relevant part for you:

#### To change the project toolset

1. In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for your project (not for your solution) and then choose Properties to open your project Property Pages dialog box.
2. In the Property Pages dialog box, open the Configuration drop-down list and then select All Configurations.
3. In the left pane of the dialog box, expand Configuration Properties and then select General.
4. In the right pane, select Platform Toolset and then select the toolset you want from the drop-down list. For example, if you have installed the Visual Studio 2010 toolset, select Visual Studio 2010 (v100) to use it for your project.
5. Choose the OK button.

If you have multiple projects/libraries, it's best if they all use the same toolset.

Comment: I reviewed that article but cannot find <TargetFrameworkVersion> in my project file. Also if I try to change the platform toolset, I get a MessageBox that says "An error has occurred.. one or more values are invalid. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: userSuppliedValue." I have done this in other projects before. Is my project file corrupted somehow?

Comment: You can't  find <TargetFrameworkVersion> in your project file because I think you said it was blank, so it was inheriting the default, which is specified in a configuration file in the Visual C++ directories. The error appears to be a VC++ issues. One other post that mentions it can be found at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5bd99816-c282-4700-aad0-e8bf682c5095/vs-2015-update-2-breaks-build-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-winsdkverh-no-such?forum=vcgeneral.

Comment: Changing the platform toolset doesn't appear to make any changes in the project file regarding include or lib paths. It just changes the value <PlatformToolset>. Apparently that tells the compiler something??? So now I have to guess where the compiler is looking for include files that it cannot find. Do you know where it looks for includes when PlatformToolset is set to v140_xp?